# Quarkus Security JPA with multiple persistence unit

Tags: security, jpa, quarkus

Is there a way to use quarkus security jpa with multiple persistence unit ? It seems that JpaIdentityProvider inject directly the entity manager factory which lead to an  "Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" exeception.

May be a workaround is possible ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this, I configured the default datasource - `quarkus.hibernate-orm.datasource` - with the datasource that has the User table, like this:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.hibernate-orm.datasource=security
quarkus.hibernate-orm.packages=eventmgr.entity.security

quarkus.datasource.security.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.security.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:security;
quarkus.flyway.security.migrate-at-start=true
quarkus.flyway.security.locations=db/security

quarkus.hibernate-orm."summary".datasource=summary
quarkus.hibernate-orm."summary".packages=eventmgr.entity.summary
quarkus.datasource.summary.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/summary
quarkus.datasource.summary.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.summary.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.summary.password=postgres
quarkus.flyway.summary.migrate-at-start=true
quarkus.flyway.summary.locations=db/migration

quarkus.hibernate-orm."event".datasource=event
quarkus.hibernate-orm."event".packages=eventmgr.entity.event
quarkus.datasource.event.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.event.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/client
quarkus.datasource.event.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.event.password=postgres
```

Tested with Quarkus 1.13.7